# Unable to open system settings

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system. I tried to open the system settings icon the launcher and the panel on the top right corner of the screen. I tried running `gnome-control-center` and unity-control-center` and I get this error:-

```
(unity-control-center:26474): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'unity-control-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 182 error_code 2 request_code 154 (GLX) minor_code 24)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

System Settings started working after I restarted the system.

Comment: Still dont know why the error occurred though!